# POST json via StringEntity

Tags: java, json, post

i'm trying to send some json-data from client to server:

here's a snippet of client-app code:

```
JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer().object()
.key("content").value("Hi there!").endObject();
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("JSON: " + json.toString());
httppost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

how should i retrieve this data in serever-app code?
for example, if i use NameValuePair instead of StringEntity, i will retrieve it with `req.getParameter("content");` in server-code. But what about StringEntity with JSON?

---

UPDATE:
Ok, i get it, here's solution (without parsing):

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    String data = sb.toString();
}
```